# EAGLE 9.3.0 - No mapping errors - How to solve them?

Tags: eaglecad

I've created a preliminary schematic without any package, because at drawing phase were unknown. So I've used "*EXTERNAL*" attribute to my devices to allow me to add them to schematics. Now I've added packages to my devices and want to update library to change package of all this devices. But when I'm trying to perform this operation, I get this two errors:

**"No mapping between external and non external devices. XXXXX (external) can't be mapped to new version of XXXXX (not external)" where XXXXX is the name of a single device.**

[image]

I've tried to delete all this devices from schematics and add a copy with a different name. But nothing. Seem that my schematic stuck with old device.

A temporary solution was to create another device with another name. But this create me a redundancy inside my library and also another error:

[image]

How I can solve this problem if someone already encounter it?

p.s. I've already tried to contact Autodesk but without answer.

Comment: Have you tried the replace feature?

Comment: I don't know how to use it in this particular case. I've not created a component that I need to replace with another one. It's the same components where _EXTERNAL_ attribute were removed and a footprint were added. After that, button "Update Libraries" or "Add Component" inside schematic editor generate me this error.